# Alternative to php-mp4info to read mp4 metadata with php

Tags: php, drupal, metadata, mp4, dimensions

I'm trying to get video dimensions of mp4 files with php within the Drupal structure.

The php-mp4info class seems to be under-developed and although I was able to read the dimensions of some mp4 files using its test/demo file and tweaking the code according to some suggestions posted in the class [issues page](http://code.google.com/p/php-mp4info/issues/list), I wasn't able to do the same thing on the server in a Drupal .tpl.php file.

Is there any alternative for mp4 metadata reading? php-mp4info is just not working for me right now..

Thanks in advance,

Pedro

Answer (score 0):

If you have ffmpeg on your server you can use it via `exec` or there is nice php warper for it: [ffmpeg-php](http://ffmpeg-php.sourceforge.net/)

Comment: Unfortunately ffmpeg would is not an option because of the server in use. Thanks though!